# Why won't the text display

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program where you type text in the entry box, and then when you click a button it shows the text below, but it doesn't work, as soon as i click the button it gives me an error?

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def myhello():
    text = ment.get()
    label = Label(text=entry).grid()
    return

ment = str()
root = Tk()
root.title('Tutorial')
root.geometry('400x400')

button = Button(root, text='Button',command = myhello).place(x='160', y='5')

entry = Entry(textvariable=ment).place(x='5', y= '10 ')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `place` isn't normally used. You should learn to use `pack` and `grid` -- they are much more flexible, and generally lead to UIs that have good resize behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `StringVar`, not `str`.

You are using `grid`, `place` at the same time. Pick one.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def myhello():
    text = ment.get()
    label['text'] = text

root = Tk()
root.title('Tutorial')
root.geometry('400x400')

button = Button(root, text='Button',command=myhello).place(x='160', y='5')
label = Label(root, text='')
label.place(x=5, y=30)

ment = StringVar()
entry = Entry(textvariable=ment).place(x='5', y= '10 ')

root.mainloop()
```